# Ionic 4 tab bar overflow

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want made layout like this : [image]

But got this: [image]

My button is cutting by tab-bar. 
How I can solve this?
I try to add "overflow: visible" for all of tags, but it's doesn't work.
My template:

```css
.place-button-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ion-tabs>
...
    <ion-tab-button tab="places">
      <div class="place-button-wrapper" >
        <img class="tabs-icon" src="assets/icons/mapiconelepse.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </ion-tab-button>
...
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fix that just adding "contain: none" to my ion-tabs.

Comment: If it doesn't work, add "contain: none" to ion-tab-bar in your css

Answer (score 3):

I've created a mix of all answers:

```
// as mentioned about
ion-tabs { contain: none; }
ion-tab-bar { contain: none }

 // a wrapper for the position
.buttonWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}

// for the overflow
ion-tab-button::part(native){
   overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: I was only using ion-tab-button without ion-tabs or ion-tab-bar.ion-tab-button::part(native){
   overflow: visible;
} worked for me

Comment: worked like magic. Just wrote this in tabs.page.scss file and it worked

Answer (score 1):

If it doesnt work by adding "contain: none" to ion-iabs, then add "contain: none" to ion-tab-bar.

```
ion-tabs { contain: none; }
```

OR

```
ion-tab-bar { contain: none }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me (I know, maybe it is not the cleanest solution, but I didn't find other way)

I created a recursive method and in this method tried to get all tab buttons, if it doesn't, I use a setTimeout to recall the method (the setTimeout is necessary to avoid to fill the stack) and after found all the buttons, I accessed to the shadow root of everyone, and I changed the overflow value:

```
  setStyle() {
    const all = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-has-icon');

    if(all.length === 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setStyle();
      }, 0);
      return;
    }

    all.forEach(el => {
      el.shadowRoot.querySelector('.button-native').setAttribute('style','overflow: inherit')
    });
  }
```