# Ionic 4 tab cutting on parent element

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to move the ion-tab-button a bit up putting position absolute, top -30px and overflow visible but none of this works. I tried already putting contain none on ion-tabs (a solution for a user here in stack overflow) and didnt work either.

PS1. Even if I try to create a new Ionic 4 project an implement this doesnt work.

PS2. I had success on Ionic 3

Can anyone help me please?

[image: Check how the tab is being displayed]

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by simply putting ion-tab-button elements outside ion-tab-bar and adding below css.

```
ion-tab-button{
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 0.5vh;
  z-index: 999;
  height: auto;
}

.tab-1 {
  left: 5%;
}

.tab-2 {
  left: 31%;
}

.tab-3 {
  left: 54%;
}

.tab-4 {
  left: 79%;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it simply by just updating CSS because Ionic provides web component.

Ionic web components base a lot of their styles on the values of **CSS4 variables**, we can change the values of those variables to modify the internal styling of the web component only.

Please read this article :
https://www.joshmorony.com/shadow-dom-usage-in-ionic-web-components/

you can make changes into below css variables:

```
 -padding-top: -30px;
--padding-bottom: 6px;
--padding-start: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

on Ionic 5 we need to manipulate de shadow DOM...
I put my solution in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301631/4320596